# How to SUM the value Getting From Database Using FutureBuilder And Print It In Screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

i'm trying to sum the value of
`totalPurchasePrice`
`totalRefuelCost`
`totalServiceCost`
`totalExpenseCost`
`totalInsuranceCost`
`totalPermitCost`
`totalPUCCost`
`totalAccidentCost`
and print it in `totalExpenditure` that i have initialized in code.

code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vehicleexpensemanager/database/database.dart';

class Summary extends StatefulWidget {
  dynamic vehicleModelNameController;
  dynamic vehicleRegistrationNumberController;
  dynamic vehicleID;

  Summary(
      {super.key,
      this.vehicleModelNameController,
      this.vehicleRegistrationNumberController,
      this.vehicleID});

  @override
  State<Summary> createState() => _SummaryState();
}
class _SummaryState extends State<Summary> {
  bool includePrice = false;
  double totalExpenditure = 0;
  double totalPurchasePrice = 0;
  double totalRefuelCost = 0;
  double totalServiceCost = 0;
  double totalExpenseCost = 0;
  double totalInsuranceCost = 0;
  double totalPermitCost = 0;
  double totalPUCCost = 0;
  double totalAccidentCost = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        title: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Summary",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 4,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  widget.vehicleModelNameController,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Text("-"),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Text(
                  widget.vehicleRegistrationNumberController,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Card(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text("Include Purchase Price"),
                  Checkbox(
                    value: includePrice,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        includePrice = value!;
                      });
                      if (includePrice) {
                        totalExpenditure = totalRefuelCost +
                            totalServiceCost +
                            totalExpenseCost +
                            totalInsuranceCost +
                            totalPermitCost +
                            totalPUCCost +
                            totalAccidentCost +
                            totalPurchasePrice;
                      }
                      if (!includePrice) {
                        totalExpenditure = totalRefuelCost +
                            totalServiceCost +
                            totalExpenseCost +
                            totalInsuranceCost +
                            totalPermitCost +
                            totalPUCCost +
                            totalAccidentCost;
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text("Total Expenditure"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(totalExpenditure.toString()),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text("₹/Km"),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, Object?>>>(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot != null && snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    totalPurchasePrice =
                        double.parse(snapshot.data![index]['Total'].toString());
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Card(
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text("Purchase Price"),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(totalPurchasePrice.toString()),
                                    Text("data"),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "No Data",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            future: MyDatabase().getTotalVehicleCount(widget.vehicleID),
          ),
          FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, Object?>>>(
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot != null && snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      totalRefuelCost = double.parse(
                          snapshot.data![index]['Total'].toString());
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          Card(
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text("Refuel"),
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        (totalRefuelCost.toString()),
                                      ),
                                      Text("data"),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "No Data",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
              future: MyDatabase().getTotalRefuelCount(widget.vehicleID)
              ),
          FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, Object?>>>(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot != null && snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    totalServiceCost =
                        double.parse(snapshot.data![index]['Total'].toString());
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Card(
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text("Service"),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(totalServiceCost.toString()),
                                    Text("data"),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "No Data",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            future: MyDatabase().getTotalServiceCount(widget.vehicleID),
          ),
          FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, Object?>>>(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot != null && snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                   totalExpenseCost =
                        double.parse(snapshot.data![index]['Total'].toString());
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Card(
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text("Expense"),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(totalExpenseCost.toString()),
                                    Text("data"),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "No Data",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            future: MyDatabase().getTotalExpenseCount(widget.vehicleID),
          ),
          FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, Object?>>>(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot != null && snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                   totalInsuranceCost =
                        double.parse(snapshot.data![index]['Total'].toString());
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Card(
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text("Insurance"),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(totalInsuranceCost.toString()),
                                    Text("data"),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "No Data",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            future: MyDatabase().getTotalInsuranceCount(widget.vehicleID),
          ),
          FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, Object?>>>(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot != null && snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                   totalPermitCost =
                        double.parse(snapshot.data![index]['Total'].toString());
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Card(
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text("Permit"),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(totalPermitCost.toString()),
                                    Text("data"),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "No Data",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            future: MyDatabase().getTotalPermitCount(widget.vehicleID),
          ),
          FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, Object?>>>(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot != null && snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                   totalPUCCost =
                        double.parse(snapshot.data![index]['Total'].toString());
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Card(
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text("PUC"),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(totalPUCCost.toString()),
                                    Text("data"),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "No Data",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            future: MyDatabase().getTotalPUCCount(widget.vehicleID),
          ),
          FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, Object?>>>(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot != null && snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    totalAccidentCost =
                        double.parse(snapshot.data![index]['Total'].toString());
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Card(
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text("Accident"),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(totalAccidentCost.toString()),
                                    Text("data"),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "No Data",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            future: MyDatabase().getTotalAccidentCount(widget.vehicleID),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

now the thing not happening is when i check or uncheck the checkbox then only `totalExpenditure` value is updating by default when i navigate abovescreen the `totalExpenditure`'s default value 0 is showing instead of this i want to display the sum of all variable excluding purchase price by default as checkbox is by default unchecked.

and i think beacuse of futurebuilder `totalExpenditure` is setting before value come from database.

screen i got when i navigate first time

[image]

screen i want when i navigate first time

[image]

please help me to find solution for this and tell me if any other part of code is required to solve it.

i will provide it.

Answer (score 1):

FutureBuilder will take some time to fetch data, calling method inside build will recall on every state and api gets called.

```
future: MyDatabase().getTotalVehicleCount(widget.vehicleID),
```

You can create a state variable for this.

```
class _SummaryState extends State<Summary> {

late final vehicleFuture = MyDatabase().getTotalVehicleCount(widget.vehicleID);
...

Widget build(BuilContext context){
  .....
  future: vehicleFuture, /// on FutureBuilder
```

Find more about [Fixing a common FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder problem](https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg)

Comment: thank you for solution i have tried this thing also but still when i navigate first time `totalExpenditure` is showing 0` actually the value is storing in variavle i have created so it is still taking time.